# How to use relative paths in the given below code?

Tags: java

Consider the code sample below. Migrator class takes two input files, processes it and writes the output to final.tbl.
I want final.tbl to be created on the same path where the folder of input files is present.
Also the execute method should take relative path of this generated final.tbl file.

```
 public class Migrator{
      public void Migrate(String path1,String path2){
          PrintStream out = new PrintStream("final.tbl");//I need relative path as that of input folder path i.e path1,path2
           //.....
           //.....Processing 
      }
 }

 class MainProcess{
       public execute(String path){
          //here the execute method should the the relative path of above final.tbl file
       }

       public static void main(String args[]){

       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Path path = Paths.get(path1);
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(path.getParent().toString() + "\\final.tbl");
```

Comment: Thank you.what abt the next step for class MainProces

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `getAbsolutePath` to get path to your input files:

```
public class Migrator{
      public void Migrate(String path1,String path2){
          File f = new File(path1);
          String absolutePath = f.getAbsolutePath(); // use absolutePath for your PrintStream
          PrintStream out = new PrintStream(absolutePath);//I need relative path as that of input folder path i.e path1,path2
           //.....
           //.....Processing 
      }
 }
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getParentFile()`

```
File target = new File(new File(path1).getParentFile(), "final.tbl");
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(target);
```